# prevent Composer update to reinstall

Tags: php, laravel, git, github, composer-php

I have a Laravel project with some dependencies. One of those dependencies is our own package. I need to do work on that package. The setup is that I symlink our package to a git repository.

vendor/acme/ourpackage -> ~/ourpackagerepo

I make changes in the repository, commit and then run Composer update in the parent to get an updated composer.lock. This used to work fine. But after we moved from Gitlab to Github, `composer update acme/ourpackage` does:

- Removing acme/ourpackage (dev-feature/fixedinformationlog fae89ac)
- Installing acme/ourpackage (dev-feature/fixedinformationlog 9bd7d4d):

And thus overwritng the symlink! Then I have to delete the folder and create a new symlink to keep working. That is a hassle, mostly because PHPStorm needs to re-index.

Snippets from composer.json:

```
"repositories": [{
  "type": "vcs",
  "url": "git@github.com:acme/package.git"


"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.0.12"
    },
    "use-github-api": false
```

Any ideas on how to make composer only update, or leave tha files alone and only update composer.lock?

Comment: composer update acme/ourpackage --lock says: "Nothing to install or update" and the .lock file is not updated

Comment: Add it as a path instead of a repository: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I don´t see how that would work when i deploy to the server. How can the package be installed when composer doesn´t know where the git-repository is?

Comment: @jrewing Were you able to resolve this? Does my answer offer any assistance?

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will check it out soon, I'm probably on a different timezone than you :)

Comment: A bit of information I left out is that colleagues of mine didn´t encounter this issue. And their symlink is left intact on "composer update". I don´t understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a couple options here:

#### 1. Composer Repository Paths

As [pointed out by @Loek](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path), you can use a **path** repository. This exists to address scenarios that do not typically fall under a VCS (Version Control System such as Git) or as a file artifact. Per the documentation, you use it like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../packages/my-package",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/package": "*"
    }
}
```

The most important part to pay attention to is this:

> **The local package will be symlinked if possible**, in which case the
>   output in the console will read Symlinking from
>   ../../packages/my-package. If symlinking is not possible the package
>   will be copied. In that case, the console will output Mirrored from
>   ../../packages/my-package.
>
> Instead of default fallback strategy **you can force to use symlink with
>   "symlink": true or mirroring with "symlink": false option**. Forcing
>   mirroring can be useful when deploying or generating package from a
>   monolithic repository.

This option makes the most sense to me and is what I would personally go with.

#### 2. Multiple Composer Configs w/ Environment Variables

Another option is to use the `COMPOSER` environment variable [as described here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#environment-variables). This will allow you to load a different `composer.json` file than the default named one. So you might have two files and depending on what you set the environment variable to, it will load the appropriate one and create a matching lock file:

- composer.json
- composer-dev.json

Ok, so why in the world would you want to do that? Well due to the way you are trying to work on your package locally (with an active symlink), but don't want that to occur in production, this could potentially work if the first option doesn't.

I should note that your goal should always be to have a single config that works the same across environments (i.e. local, staging, production). I understand that you want to see local changes to your repository immediately in your app and going through the process of commit/push/pull for each change is ridiculous.

---

#### Additional Reading/Resources:

- https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/601
- https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4011
- https://github.com/franzliedke/studio

Comment: I´m thinking a combination of the two might work. Because if I only use Paths, deployment (composer install) won´t work on the production server. But if I use paths locally (in an alternative composer.json) and repository everywhere else it might work